# Change Buddypress Admin Profile Page Permalink

Tags: permalinks, admin, users, buddypress

Does anybody know how to change the default admin profile permalink in Buddypress which is: **domain.com/members/admin/** to this: **domain.com/members/MyUserName/**

I tried to change my name and it doesn't changes the permalink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a WP issue, not a BP issue.

User names cannot be changed via WP.

You could create another administrator account, using the user name you want, and then delete the 'admin' user.

Or you could use a database tool like phpmyadmin to access the users table.
Find the row for 'admin' and change the name there.

Answer (score 1):

As @shanebp says, it's a WP issue.

Using PhpMyAdmin, or any other SQL-interface, use this query:

```
UPDATE wp_users 
SET user_login = "new_user_login", user_nicename = "new_user_nicename"
WHERE user_login = "current_login_name";
```

and replace the strings with your username and nicename-info.

Edit: The user_nicename is optional, but could be useful, as WP-default is to have the same string in user_login and user_nicename